# How to make marshmallow obey `ro.secure=0`

Tags: rooting, boot, 6.0-marshmallow

I'm using a Nexus 5X with release 6.0.0 (MDB08M).  I unlocked the bootloader with `fastboot oem unlock`, then created a boot image with a `/default.prop` file containing `ro.secure=0`.  This appears to work, in that when I boot my device, I get:

```
shell@bullhead:/ $ getprop ro.secure
0
```

Unfortunately, though `adb root` seems to succeed and reports:

```
restarting adbd as root
```

It does not get me a root shell.  `ps` confirms `adbd` is still running as the shell user.  My question is how to make `adbd` obey `ro.secure`, or whether there is some other easy way to get root by modifying `/default.prop` or changing the kernel command-line arguments.  I know there are third-party tools such as SuperSU, but I'm hoping to get a root shell without loading any third-party software on my phone.

To reproduce what I did, you can grab `boot.img` out of the [Nexus factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en#bullhead) (unzipping `image-bullhead-mdb08m.zip`).  Unpack the boot image using [`split_bootimg_pl`](http://www.enck.org/tools/split_bootimg_pl.txt).  Unpack and repack `boot.img-ramdisk.gz` (I packed it using `find . | bsdcpio -R 0:0 -H newc -o |gzip -9 > ../newramfs.gz`).  Create a `new-boot.img` using [mkbootimg](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/android/platform_system_core/master/mkbootimg/mkbootimg) as follows:

```
mkbootimg -o new-boot.img --pagesize 4096 --base 0 --kernel_offset 0x8000 --ramdisk_offset 0x2000000 --tags_offset 0x1e00000 --kernel boot.img-kernel --ramdisk boot.img-ramdisk.gz --cmdline "console=ttyHSL0,115200,n8 androidboot.hardware=bullhead boot_cpus=0-5 lpm_levels.sleep_disabled=1 msm_poweroff.download_mode=0"
```

And finally of course flash `new-boot.img` with `fastboot flash boot new-boot.img`.